# Manipulating a DataFrame created from a dict(tuple-float)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to create a DataFrame from a dictionary that has the below structure.

```
imgAlbmShrDict = {('10', 'photo_album_57'): 20.0,
 ('10', 'photo_album_8'): 20.0,
 ('1061', 'photo_album_29'): 100.0,
 ('1061', 'photo_album_90'): 90.0,
 ('1102', 'photo_album_29'): 80.0,
 ('1102', 'photo_album_90'): 60.0,
 ('1300', 'photo_album_15'): 100.0,
 ('1300', 'photo_album_89'): 60.0,
 ('1301', 'photo_album_15'): 88.88888888888889,
 ('1301', 'photo_album_89'): 60.0
}
```

`pd.DataFrame(imgAlbmShrDict,index=['Proportion']).transpose()`

```
                    Proportion
10   photo_album_57   20.000000
     photo_album_8    20.000000
1061 photo_album_29  100.000000
     photo_album_90   90.000000
1102 photo_album_29   80.000000
     photo_album_90   60.000000
1300 photo_album_15  100.000000
     photo_album_89   60.000000
1301 photo_album_15   88.888889
     photo_album_89   60.000000
```

The output is exactly how I need, but I am unable to extract only the the first two columns from the data frame. 
The first column actually is an image ID and the second column is a album in which the image appeared.

I need help in accessing the columns and a way to add a column whilst preserving a structure.

Required output:

```
                     Proportion  URL
10   photo_album_57   20.000000  www.something.com/10.jpeg
     photo_album_8    20.000000
1061 photo_album_29  100.000000  www.something.com/1061.jpeg
     photo_album_90   90.000000
1102 photo_album_29   80.000000  www.something.com/1102.jpeg
     photo_album_90   60.000000
1300 photo_album_15  100.000000  www.something.com/1300.jpeg
     photo_album_89   60.000000
1301 photo_album_15   88.888889  www.something.com/1301.jpeg
     photo_album_89   60.000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html), because first two columns is [`Multiindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html):

```
print (df.index.get_level_values(0))
Index(['10', '10', '1061', '1061', '1102', '1102', '1300', '1300', '1301',
       '1301'],
      dtype='object')

df['URL'] = 'www.something.com/' + df.index.get_level_values(0) + '.jpg'
print (df) 
                     Proportion                         URL
10   photo_album_57   20.000000    www.something.com/10.jpg
     photo_album_8    20.000000    www.something.com/10.jpg
1061 photo_album_29  100.000000  www.something.com/1061.jpg
     photo_album_90   90.000000  www.something.com/1061.jpg
1102 photo_album_29   80.000000  www.something.com/1102.jpg
     photo_album_90   60.000000  www.something.com/1102.jpg
1300 photo_album_15  100.000000  www.something.com/1300.jpg
     photo_album_89   60.000000  www.something.com/1300.jpg
1301 photo_album_15   88.888889  www.something.com/1301.jpg
     photo_album_89   60.000000  www.something.com/1301.jpg
```

Maybe need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='URL')
print (df) 
                     Proportion                         URL
10   photo_album_57   20.000000    www.something.com/10.jpg
1061 photo_album_29  100.000000  www.something.com/1061.jpg
1102 photo_album_29   80.000000  www.something.com/1102.jpg
1300 photo_album_15  100.000000  www.something.com/1300.jpg
1301 photo_album_15   88.888889  www.something.com/1301.jpg
```

Another solution with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and set column names:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['ID','Album','Proportion']
df['URL'] = 'www.something.com/' + df['ID'] + '.jpg'
print (df)
     ID           Album  Proportion                         URL
0    10  photo_album_57   20.000000    www.something.com/10.jpg
1    10   photo_album_8   20.000000    www.something.com/10.jpg
2  1061  photo_album_29  100.000000  www.something.com/1061.jpg
3  1061  photo_album_90   90.000000  www.something.com/1061.jpg
4  1102  photo_album_29   80.000000  www.something.com/1102.jpg
5  1102  photo_album_90   60.000000  www.something.com/1102.jpg
6  1300  photo_album_15  100.000000  www.something.com/1300.jpg
7  1300  photo_album_89   60.000000  www.something.com/1300.jpg
8  1301  photo_album_15   88.888889  www.something.com/1301.jpg
9  1301  photo_album_89   60.000000  www.something.com/1301.jpg
```

EDIT1:

Thank you [`stephen`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826045/manipulating-a-dataframe-created-from-a-dicttuple-float#comment63115607_37826127) for solution.

I try make it better by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
mask = ~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated()
print (mask)
[ True False  True False  True False  True False  True False]

subindex = df.index[mask]

df.loc[subindex, 'URL'] = 'www.something.com/' + subindex.get_level_values(0) + '.jpg'
df.URL.fillna('', inplace=True)
print (df)
                     Proportion                         URL
10   photo_album_57   20.000000    www.something.com/10.jpg
     photo_album_8    20.000000                            
1061 photo_album_29  100.000000  www.something.com/1061.jpg
     photo_album_90   90.000000                            
1102 photo_album_29   80.000000  www.something.com/1102.jpg
     photo_album_90   60.000000                            
1300 photo_album_15  100.000000  www.something.com/1300.jpg
     photo_album_89   60.000000                            
1301 photo_album_15   88.888889  www.something.com/1301.jpg
     photo_album_89   60.000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response. But however I only want to print the URL once per image id. Is there a way to merge those cells?

Comment: I add another solution, where is clear that first column `ID` has duplicated values (in first salution too, but Multiindex doesnt show this duplicity - see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object) and parameter `display.multi_sparse`)

Comment: @SreejithMenon: if you really want to have the output as shown in your original question, you can apply @jezrael's solution to a `subindex = df.groupby(level=0).head(1).index` only, ie `df.loc[subindex, 'URL'] = 'www.something.com/' + subindex.get_level_values(0) + '.jpg'` (possibly followed by `df = df.fillna("")`).

Comment: drop_duplicates is not a viable solution since I need to preserve the duplicates on ID. I think I have to figure out a way to preserve the format. I might try using group_by maybe.